Remove Safe mode completely from an Android from the root
No app blockers works as I can go into safe mode and delete the app blockers.
How do I tune my Samsung Galaxy S24 enough to not have an option to go into safe mode altogether?

Sorry, we don't allow monetary incentives on Stack Exchange because everything is for public, not personal usage. Meanwhile, have you searched and browsed existing questions and read their answers?

The app blockers fail because they try to do something current Android versions aren't designed for. Wait for Android 15, it seems that Android will OS level support for locking apps. https://www.androidauthority.com/android-15-private-space-settings-3431105/

@Robert, shouldn't that be an answer?
